# Excel VBA AutoFilter select row which is filter equal to key1 and minimum of key2

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

*Spoiler Alert: I dont want a formula based approach i want to use the worksheet as a data store not a calculator*

The question here is

> Is there a smart way I can do step 4 with autofilter?

I have data in an excel range which is

| Key | Time |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 3 |
| C | 3 |
| C | 3 |
| A | 3 |
| B | 2 |

So can have duplicate rows.

I want to filter the rows where `key` in `(A, C)` which has the smallest `time` for each `key`, so that would yield

| Key | Time |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| C | 3 |

I can do this "brute force" by

1. define range which is data
2. define array which is filter
3. filter and delete rows with unwanted keys
4. (brute force bit) sort by time step through each row and delete not first rows

***Is there a smart way I can do step 4 with autofilter?*** I need to filter on a secondary key and take the first value. I kind of feel I should be able to do this with `xlFilterTop10` but cant figure it out. Long day

**ps**
I know I can do this by setting up the sheet as an ADO source and performing sql but would prefer not to ...

```
Option Explicit

Sub help_me_please()

  Dim arr(1) As Variant
  arr(0) = "A"
  arr(1) = "C"
  
  Dim rIn As Range
  Dim rOut As Range
  Set rIn = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a1")
  Set rOut = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2").Range("a1")
  
  rIn.CurrentRegion.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=arr, Operator:=xlFilterValues
  
  'copy filtered in to output sheet
  rIn.CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=rOut
  
  'remove filter
  rIn.CurrentRegion.AutoFilter
    
  rOut.CurrentRegion.Sort key1:=rOut.Range("a1"), order1:=xlAscending, _
  key2:=rOut.Range("b1"), order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
  
  Dim r As Range
  Dim i As Long
  
  Set r = rOut.Offset(1, 0)
  i = 0
  While Not IsEmpty(r.Offset(i, 0).Value)
    
    If r.Offset(i, 0).Value = r.Offset(i - 1, 0).Value Then
      'remove the not-first row
      r.Offset(i, 0).EntireRow.Delete
    Else
      ' move to next item to check
      i = i + 1
    End If
  Wend
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not use formulae? MINIF?

Comment: @SJR thanks for taking the time to make the suggestion: I dont want a formula based approach i want to use the spreadsheet as a data store not a calculator - to reiterate/clarify my post I'm interested in an elegant VBA improvement on the code i have posted , thanks again

Comment: You can always apply formulae through VBA. If it's a data store, why are you deleting rows?

Comment: Yes thank you @SJR I'm familiar with applying formulae through VBA, thanks. Deleting rows is a valid operation on a data store and for avoidance of doubt this is not my live application, just a working example to isolate and demonstrate the question. Thanks again for taking the time

Comment: You seem rather set on a particular approach? At the risk of teaching my grandmother to suck eggs, you could add a formula in a new column to pick the minimum value for each key, filter on that, delete unwanted rows and then delete formula column. All with VBA so nothing would ever be seen.

Comment: Thank again @SJR - As i said I know how i could do it with `minif`/putting formulas, adding temporary columns, checking recalcs, hiding screen updating, deleting columns etc, but I think there are more efficient ways, more elegant ways more extensible ways. I also know how i could do it by treating the sheet as an sql table - possibly the most elegant solution as i do effectively want the result of a table query. I dont need any solution, I have an ok one already. What I'm looking for is a smart, efficient programmatic solution and using formulas doesnt do that IMHO. I do appreciate your input

Comment: If your code works you should put this on Code Review instead.

Comment: I'm posing a clear question in the body of my post and I have also now made that more prominent at the beginning. I think my post stays here as any solution would be of value to others I think. Separately thanks for bringing my attention to Code Review I didnt know about that I'll use that for sure.